# How to properly reassign a value in an array of options?

Tags: rust

Trying to update a value in an array of options:

```
static mut ILIST: [Option<u32>; 5] = [None, None, None, None, None];

fn main() {

    unsafe {
        ILIST[0] = Some(10);

        match &ILIST[0].as_mut() {
            None => println!("Is none"),
            Some(n) => {
                *n = 5;
            },
        }

        match ILIST[0] {
            None => println!("Is none"),
            Some(n) => {
                assert_eq!(n, 5);
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Gives the following compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:10
   |
17 |                 *n = 5;
   |                      ^ expected `&mut u32`, found integer
   |
help: consider dereferencing here to assign to the mutable borrowed piece of memory
   |
17 |                 **n = 5;
   |                 ^^^
```

Updating the specified code to the following:

```
        Some(n) => {
            **n = 5;
        },
```

Results in another compiler error:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `**n` which is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 |                 **n = 5;
   |                 ^^^^^^^ `n` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written
```

Any insight into what's going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `&` in the first match: `match ILIST[0].as_mut()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the reference:

```rust
static mut ILIST: [Option<u32>; 5] = [None, None, None, None, None];

fn main() {

    unsafe {
        ILIST[0] = Some(10);
        // not a ref
        match ILIST[0].as_mut() {
            None => println!("Is none"),
            Some(n) => *n = 5,
        }

        match ILIST[0] {
            None => println!("Is none"),
            Some(n) => assert_eq!(n, 5),
        }
    }
}
```